# Best approach for GPS location retrieval and comparing values in the background?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, kotlin

I am working on a project that retrieves GPS coordinates in the background and compares those to given GPS coordinates to check for equality.

I have been thinking of using an IntentService to retrieve GPS coordinates while the app is not in the foreground.

However, is it the best approach for what I am trying to do? I would like to continuously update the location coordinates and compare those directly to inputted values.

A little hint would be really helpful!

Thank you very much,

Comment: hope you are aware of the changes Q is going to bring in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Using an Intent Service is not a good idea. Intent services are used to do a task (retrieve your current GPS position for example), and then, shutdown. Consider using a Service and start it as "START_STICKY" to make it work on background permanently:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```